# Many-to-many with extra column, but grouped together where extra column is a list

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have a join table with an extra column for a many-to-many relation between Users and Projects. It looks like this:

| user_id (pk) | project_id (pk) | role (pk) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | MANAGER |
| 2 | 1 | WORKER |
| 1 | 2 | MANAGER |
| 1 | 2 | WORKER |

In this example, project 1 has two participants, user 1 is there, with the role of a manager, user 2 is there with the role of a worker. In project 2, there is only one participant, user 1, which is in the role of a manager and a worker.

What I want to accomplish is a Java representation like this:

```
@Entity(...)
class ProjectRole {
    // some annotations
    private User user;

    // some annotations
    private Project project;
    
    // some annotations
    private Set<String> roles;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I'm aware of two indirect ways to get such an object.

Alternative 1: Map an Entity of the table with:

```
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
User user;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
Project project;

@Id
String role;
```

and combine multiple hits for the same user (per project) and map it to an object like the wanted structure above, but this would not allow to use sortings or pagination in the future and it would be nice to get the target structure directly.

Alternative 2: I could create an artifical Table `participants` with an artifical `participant.id` and use this in an `participant_roles` table. So I get two entities, while the first one can have a `Set<ParticipantRole>`. But I have to save a lot of unnecessary information in the database.

Maybe it is impossible, since an Entity-instance is more or less a representation of a row in the database, so I will always get multiple entries per user (per project). Or is there something I haven't seen so far to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the option 1 and expose the details through some dedicated method that does the grouping on-demand or in a `@PostLoad` event listener. Hibernate/JPA needs the information to be bidirectional and the kind of mapping you want here is more or less a projection of the normalized data.